# What does "To be it to be followed" mean

Tags: grammar, verbs

In this sentence :
*This trend, **were it to be** followed, would spell disaster for the country*

What does it means and how to use it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inversion of subject and verb (auxiliary) in a subordinate clause is a literary construction equivalent to "if".

So

> were it to be followed

is a literary way of saying

> if it were to be followed

There is no difference in meaning between them.

I also cannot find any difference in meaning between those and

> if it were followed

In other contexts the structure "[be] to [verb]" suggests an obligation or compulsion, for example "He is to go straight home after this", but in a conditional ("If it were to..." or "Were it to ...") that meaning doesn't make sense. So I don't know why we use this form, but it is quite normal (in the somewhat formal register being used).

Comment: Thanks i understand now !

Answer (score 0):

'Were to' can be used as an if/then conditional in the present or future sense.

> https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/wereto.html

In this case 'were to' is separated by the subject 'it' (trend) and 'be followed' as it relates to the trend means that it would continue.

> 'Were it to be followed' means 'if the trend continues'

Here's a rephrasing to clarify the meaning of the sentence;

> It would spell disaster for the country if this trend were to continue.